# How to Configure a NetBeans 11.1 Project to Run Remotely on aRaspberry Pi

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi

I want to use NetBeans on my Windows 8.2 laptop to compile java programs and run them on my RaspBerry Pi 4B. I have been following the Instructables "Efficient Java Development for the Raspberry Pi" available at https://www.instructables.com/id/Efficient-Development-of-Java-for-the-Raspberry-Pi/. I am using NetBeans Version 11.1 whereas these instructions relate to an earlier version. The version they describe has a project Properties dialog which displays a list of categories including a "run" item, and this item is the one used to identify the correct remote platform configured earlier in the setup sequence. With NetBeans 11.1 the project Properties dialog no longer has a "run" item and I cannot find a way of specifying the RaspBerry Pi platform as the target. Is there a way of doing this with the version of NetBeans I am using?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible solution myself. When I posed the question, I omitted to mention that the NetBeans project was created as a Java Gradle project. I am fairly new to NetBeans and did not realise the full implications of this choice. Since that time I have tried another approach and created the project as a Java Ant project. With this configuration, the "run" item is now present in the project Properties dialog and I can select the remote RaspBerry Pi platform as the target. With this change, I can now compile on my laptop and run the application on the RPi with one click of a NetBeans button.

There was no mention of this in the original article I was following, and I suspect the NetBeans project Properties dialog has changed since that time. A further post in the RaspBerry Pi forum in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59600#p445707 dated Oct 2013 highlights the same problem, but has received no replies. While I can proceed now with the Ant build process, my preference is still to stick with Gradle since I do have some familiarity with it on other projects. I have still not found any help regarding Gradle and how to identify  remote target platform, if indeed it is possible at all. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Old Netbeans didn't have Gradle / Maven options. Java projects were just java projects with Ant under the hood. I'm glad you documented how it is now. I'm just getting into remote.